# Notification when app is closed in Ionic3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I am building my app using Ionic3 and Firebase. Here users can send eatch other messages. I want when a use sends a message to another ures he/she should get a notification in the phone even when the app is closed. I have no idea how to achieve this with Ionic3.
Any suggesions please.

I can see there are mainly 2 plugins for push notifications. [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase#cordova-plugin-firebase) and [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm)

At least I can fine some tutorial for [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) in the internet. There is no clear example of any wayout given for [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase#cordova-plugin-firebase).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) and each time a user logs in using a device, a unique device ID will be registered with respect to that device. This device ID is used to send notifications. Make sure to handle this (device ID), every time a user logs in & logs out. If you do not remove the device_id from the database when a user logs out, he will continue to receive notifications.

Comment: Hi, Is there any tutorial link which describes the push notification process using this plugin. I'll be really helpfull.

Comment: @TapasMukherjee [Github](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) This might be of some help.

Comment: Hi Charu, its the same link from Github. I have gone through it and tried a lot to find out the way to implement. I am installed the plugin. What I want to understand is were in my app can I write the methods like getToken and others. Also using this. I can send push notifications from firebase portal. How do I send from one device to another.

Comment: Hey, @TapasMukherjee, I could not find a tutorial. To answer your questions, every time you log in to the app you use the getToken & onTokenRefresh. Apart from that, every time the app comes to foreground from background, you again use these functions to check if the token stored in the server is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a cordova-plugin for sending push notifications. One of the many available plugins is: [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase). This one is a good fit for Ionic 3 because there is an [ionic-native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) wrapper available.

For sending the push notification you can use a third party service (there is also one offered by ionic) or you can send them yourself from your backend.